# custom query params in firebase dynamic links for short urls

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, google-url-shortener

I am trying to use firebase dynamic links as replacement for Google's URL shortner (as they are terminating the service).

Shortlinks are being created but query params are being parsed for app specific behaviours and whenever I provide custom query params they are being ignored while creating shortLinks. Hence I could not provide custom query params.

Is there any way I can work with FDLs or should I look into another URL shortening service?

Comment: Firebaser here! Can you add an example of a link that is not doing what you intend? You shouldn't be adding URL parameters to the short link itself, but to the link that you are wrapping. Still: worth noting that for non-app use cases bit.ly and owl.ly may be better bets - dynamic links is very app focused.

Comment: Let's say I have a link https://example.com/route?page=somepage&token=sometoken  then this will not be shortened properly and in the long url I wouldn't receive this url back.

Comment: It would be easier if you can share a specific dynamic link with me that you have created that doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same lost params issue on returned shortlinks. Escaping the url worked for me:

params lost:

`"https://www.test.co.uk/testing/?utm_source=jam&utm_medium=spoon&utm_campaign=jar&utm_term=lid"`

params returned correctly:

`"https%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.co.uk%2Ftesting%2F%3Futm_source%3Djam%26utm_medium%3Dspoon%26utm_campaign%3Djar%26utm_term%3Dlid"`